# show/hide switch

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide, slidetoggle

I have the following code

```
<input type='radio' name='showhide'></input><input type='radio' name='showhide'></input>
<br/>
<label> Some tips here!</label>
```

My requirement is, when the radio button is changed, the label below will be show or hidden. It is easy to implement, but my problem is, with the show or hide of the label, the layout of the whole page will be changed. I think it is because the text in the label is longer than that of radio button. Then what should I do to prevent the change of the page's layout? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use css visibility: hidden

Answer (score 1):

First thing, there is no `</input>`. Another thing is you haven't given the value to the input.

```
<input type='radio' name='showhide' value="true" />
<input type='radio' name='showhide' value="false" />
```

Now, for the interaction, give an `ID` to the `<label>`.

```
<label id="tips"> Some tips here!</label>
```

And using JavaScript, you can do this:

```
<input type='radio' name='showhide' onclick="document.getElementById('tips').style.visibility='visible'" value="true" />
<input type='radio' name='showhide' onclick="document.getElementById('tips').style.visibility='hidden'" value="false" />
```

Comment: You are right, but this is just an example. my problem is the layout of the whole page is changed with show/hide of the label.

Comment: Yeah, as people said use `visibility`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot. I'm confused what's the difference between this method and slideToggle function in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use css visibility

```
<input type='radio' name='showhide' onclick="document.getElementById('tip').style.visibility='visible';" />
<input type='radio' name='showhide' onclick="document.getElementById('tip').style.visibility='hidden''" value="false" />

<label id="tip"> Some tips here!</label>
```